# WPF/MVVM: Opening different UserControls in same DockPanel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dockpanel

I am creating an application using the `DockPanel` for my layout.  In the 'Left' `DockPanel` I have setup a few links (Labels) that I would like to use to open different `UserControls` when a link is clicked.  I want the `UserControls` to always open in the 'Right' DockPanel when the appropriate link is clicked.

What mechanism in WPF (using MVVM) would  I use to accomplish this?  Are there any examples that I can view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general pattern to follow is this:

1. Add a `ContentPresenter` to the place in your user interface which will host the switch-able content (the right panel of the `DockPanel` in your case).
2. The visual representation of each switchable view will be represented by a user control.
3. The data of each switch-able view will be represented by a viewModel.
4. Bind the `Content` property of the `ContentPresenter` to a property in your view model that is of a viewModel type that represents the view E.G. `BoundContent`.
5. When the link is clicked, your viewModel should react to this by changing the bound property and raising the `PropertyChanged` event to notify your view.
6. For each 'view' that can be switched you will need a `DataTemplate` that maps each user control to each viewModel.

[Rachel Lims](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302677/rachel) blog contains a couple of examples which demonstrates the above:

- [Switching views in WPF/MVVM](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/)
- [Navigation with MVVM](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)