# WPF Change between controls

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls, devexpress

I have a simple application where I have a main screen with some operations, and a second screen that you access when first one is done and you press a button. See image:

[image]

**Brown areas** are fixed left menus, that will always appear in the same location. 
**Blue areas** are the screens that change from one to another.
**Red area** is trying to simulate a MDIContainer from WindowsForms.

**How can I simulate that container to**:

1. **Mantain the left static menu**
2. **Change dynamically my content due to some events/actions?**

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13864550/577417) for a general purpose way of handling this situation.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, really constructive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Static"/>
    <ContentControl x:Name="content1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Visible" >
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="One" />
            <Button Click="btn1_click" Content="Button1"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl x:Name="content2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Hidden" >
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Two" />
            <Button Click="btn2_click" Content="Button2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>

        private void btn1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            content1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            content2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void btn2_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            content1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            content2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }
```

If you can put the button above like in a menu area
Can do me dynamic stuff with Frame and Page content
This example shows passing data to the Page constructor
nextPage is a Page
could also be a UserControl

```
<Frame Name="SrchItemEditField" />

PageDocFieldDetail nextPage = new PageDocFieldDetail(df);
SrchItemEditField.Content = nextPage;
```

Comment: Thanks!! Really easy to understand, and exactly what I was looking for! Only as a curiosity: I did this once, and I remember I draw panels apart from the main design window. I'm using Visual Studio for the design. Is there any way to design the contentcontrols in a different position of the main window, so we can avoid overlaping designs, and make them appear at the same position?

Comment: See the bottom of the answer - use Pages.

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be first to use a grid control to lay out the controls (as Blam suggested) like so:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Menu control. (Whichever you see fit. The menu could be established 
         within this control, or you could use a custom UserControl depending
         on your needs.) -->
    <StackPanel />

    <!-- Content control -->
    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentHolder" 
                      Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Depending on your design pattern, there are a couple of ways to get your content to appear as desired.

If you are using MVVM, the ContentPresenter control could be *bound* to a ViewModel in the data context of your main window, like so:

```
    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentHolder" 
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Content="{Binding ContentData}" />
```

And a corresponding property would exist in your ViewModel, such as:

```
    public ViewModelBase ContentData{
      get { return _contentData; }
    }
```

If that's a lot of Greek to you, you are probably not using MVVM as your design pattern.  In that case, the code behind of your main window class could handle setting the content of the ContentPresenter with an event handler.

The gist of your event handler could be something like this:

```
    public void HandleNavigationChange(SwitchCondition sc){
      UserControl newContent = null;

      switch (sc) {
        case SwitchCondition.NavigationItem1:
          newContent = new NavigationItem1();
          break;

        case SwitchCondition.NavigationItem1:
          newContent = new NavigationItem1();
          break;
        //ETC
      }

      ContentHolder.Content = newContent;
    }
```

You could then call this method from menu item clicks, or if you like, from children controls.