# Modal Popup and views communication under MVVM pattern on C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, modalpopup

I have a large project coded with VB6 which I've been trying to upgrade to new technologies for a few months. My project consist on 6 administrative modules reunited under a client-server application. Coming from VB, my logical choice was to upgrade to .NET. After a lot of research I decide to use `C#`, `WPF` and the MVVM pattern (with Caliburn Micro).

At the beggining I had some problems, but I managed to resolve them. But now I've come to a point where I need (like every complex application) to communicate with different views and their corresponding viewModel through modal popups (or some other technique). And in this matter the MVVM pattern seems to be very restrictive or complex. A simple "Are you sure you want to delete this record (yes/no)" is a very complex task. So I'm looking for advice as how communicate views without complex artifacts as EventAgregators.

So far the only possible alternative I've found is to use the `ModalContentPresenter` class from [this blog](http://programmingwithpassion.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/displaying-modal-content-in-wpf/). The problems with this solution are:

- I need to write the father view XAML and modal XAML on the same view.
- I cannot have multiple popus from same view.

Some examples of where I'd like to use modal popups is:

- Put a button on a view to select a Client. It should open a popup with all posible clients and let the user chose one.
- Add a product popup to a customer order.

Any ideas or suggestions? Some sample code would be appreciated? Thanks!

Comment: are you familiar with `AngularJs` I would personally have gone that route..

Comment: No i'm not. What is used for? Maybe you can explain a little more about your comment.

Comment: Do a google search on AngularJS with C# it's way too long to explain but it's easy to learn especially if you are familiar with MVC

Comment: I already do that. From what i've read, AngularJs is a JavaScript Framework for HTML. My project is writted on WPF because is a desktop application, not HTML. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I am sure that you can mix and match but I don't do WPF anymore I thought that they deprecated that..LOL

Comment: My initial idea was to use Windows Forms. But i almost get sacrified when i mention it because someone tell me that windows form whas from stone age. They suggest me to use WPF instead and thats the path I toke. I hope it wasn't a bad decision.

Comment: You can never had multiple popups from the same view, if they are modal. You need to clarify more what you are trying to do. If it's just a matter of "Enter a number", then I don't usually go to all the bother of doing the MVVM route and binding to a custom class just for a simple edit. I will handle the value from the modal dialog once it is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of the linked `ModalContentPresenter` control so I will attempt to address some of your questions and concerns.

> I need to write the father view XAML and modal XAML on the same view.

You can actually write **both** views in separate files. The views can then be loaded dynamically using `DataTemplates` which will depend on the `ViewModel` that is bound to either the `Content` or `ModalContent` properties.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13864550/577417) which describes the general way in which this view switching can be achieved.

You could have a `MainViewModel` which has two properties, `PrimaryViewModel` and `SecondaryViewModel` which return appropriate view models which provide the properties and commands for the main and modal content.

You could have the following setup in `XAML`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type FooViewModel}">
    <Controls:FooView />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type BarViewModel}">
    <Controls:BarView />
</DataTemplate>

<controls:ModalContentPresenter 
              Name="modalPresenter"
              Content={Binding DataContext.PrimaryViewModel}
              ModalContent={Binding DataContext.SecondaryViewModel} />
```

When the `IsModal`property is `false`, only your `PrimaryView` will be displayed. As soon as you set the `IsModal` property to `true` the `ModalContentPresenter` will display your `SecondaryView`.

> I cannot have multiple popus from same view.

I take it you mean you want to be able to display different modal content *at different times* from the same main view.

Using the above technique this is as simple as switching the `ViewModel` that is bound to the `ModalContent` property (before displaying it by setting `IsModal` to `true`). As long as you have a `DataTemplate` for the `ViewModel` that is bound (and your `MainViewModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly), the correct content will be displayed.

> Some example on where i'd like to use modal popups is:
>
> Put a button on a view to select a Client. It should open a popup with
>   all possible clients and let the user chose one.
>
> Add a product popup to a customer order.

Once you understand the technique described above you should be able to see that the as long as you have a `View` and `ViewModel` pair you can cover any scenario you can think of.

As an example, consider viewModels that have the following interfaces:

```
public interface SelectCustomerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    event EventHandler CustomerSelected;        
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Command CustomerSelectedCommand { get; }
}

public interface MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public SelectCustomerViewModel ModalContent { get; }
    public Command SelectCustomerCommand { get; }
    public bool IsSelectingCustomer { get; }
}
```

You could have `XAML` that looks something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="ModalContentTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Select a customer">

    <DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </DataContext>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SelectCustomerViewModel}">
        <Controls:SelectCustomerView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <c:ModalContentPresenter Name="modalPresenter"
                             ModalContent={Binding ModalContent}
                             IsModal={Binding IsSelectingCustomer}>

        <!-- This is the primary content! -->
        <Grid>
            <Button Content="Select a customer"
                    Command={Binding SelectCustomerCommand} />
        </Grid>

    </c:ModalContentPresenter>

</Window>
```

Here's how it works:

1. The `IsSelectingCustomer` property of the `MainViewModel` would start off as `false`.
2. Clicking the button in the main view would invoke the `SelectCustomerCommand` object. The command would then tell the `MainViewModel` to change the `IsSelectingCustomer` property to `true`.
3. The `ModalContentPresenter` would display the view specified by the data template. The user can now only interact with the 'select customer view'.
4. Once a customer has been selected, a button can be clicked (which is bound to the `CustomerSelectedCommand` of the `SelectCustomerViewModel`) which in turn would raise the `CustomerSelected` event.
5. The `MainViewModel` would have an event handler that would respond to the `CustomerSelected` event. The handler would then read the `SelectedCustomer` property from the `SelectCustomerViewModel` and finally, it would set the `IsSelectingCustomer` property back to false, causing the modal content to be closed.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will take my time to read your answser and completly understand it, but i have to say that your approach is the best i can fiend to resolve this problem. I'm new to all this technologies so is hard to me (at the moment) to fully undestand your answer but i will make all this test! Thank you again!

Comment: In the proccess I will probably ask some more details about the code you post here, if you allow me of course. Thank you again for your time

Comment: Glad I could help. If you have any further questions, please ask.

Comment: Hi. I'm tryng to understand the first part of your answer, that is, to have Content and Modelcontent in separated files (UserControls), but i cannot make it work. I tried this: Content="{Binding DataContext.OrderViewModel}" but it doesn't work. Do i need to declare OrderViewModel as DataContext source? how? thanks!

Comment: @ericpap you need to use data templates to tell WPF which user control to load for each viewModel. The link at the top of my post will take you to some articles which explain how this is done.

Comment: Hi. I'm re-tryng to solve this problem with yor help. I Manage to do what you suggest. I create a DataTemplate for then ModalContent. But becasuse i'm using two UserControls(or two views) both have different viewmodels. So how do I make modalcontent to change the IsModal Property of parent view? thanks!

Comment: That's entirely up to you; the `ModalContentPresenter` allows you to use standard MVVM best practices to achieve your result.The example scenario above shows you how to achieve what you want using a parent-child viewModel(s) and communicates using an event (see point 5) but it doesn't have to be done this way. You could, for example, communicate via an event aggregator instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was thinking in something more simple like used a shared viewmodel between the two views, but suppose it is not posible. Also child view doesn't seem to link to it's viewmodel propeties, do you have any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't be possible to use a shared viewModel. You might need to use a `DataTemplateSelector` if you want to switch different views that share the same viewModel. If you're still struggling I would suggest you create a new question with some sample code.

Comment: Thnaks again. I follow your advice and post a new question. Can you give it a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607883/shared-viewmodel-between-two-views-in-wpf-mvvm-pattern. Thanks!